# Creating a right mouse button click event handler

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, right-click

I'd like to have a certain event handler to work when I press my ImageButton control by the right mouse button. How can I achieve this? I use asp.net.

Answer (score 0):

You must use client side technique to catch it, for example js/Jquery. Something like

`<script type="text/javascript"> $(function () { $("#ImageButton").mousedown(function (e) {
 if (e.which == "3") {
// Do magic.
} }) }); </script>`